# split dataframe column into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have been sent a file. I have read it in as a dataframe which contains only one column and over a 1,000,000 rows. Each row is a mixture of numbers and text.

I tried the following line below.

> data = data.str.split('/t',expand=True)

However I get the error below,

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

I thought maybe it was because its of type object and not string. So tried the line below however that seems to have no effect.

> data.astype('str')

How can I split this column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is one column `DataFrame`, so for one column is possible select first column by position with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
data = data.iloc[:, 0].str.split('/t',expand=True)
```

Or if psosible select first column by name:

```
data = data['col'].str.split('/t',expand=True)
```

Comment: using the first suggestion just seems to have changed the column name from some long horrible name to 0. I didn't try the second as the column name is so long

Comment: @mHelpMe - Are you sure? Because `0` here means first column of `data`

Comment: sorry it is now working, just re-ran it and indeed it worked, thanks